# Ext Js show a text above a button element

Tags: css, extjs

We are trying to develop a progress bar in which we have to align a text on top of button. We tried using different layouts but its not coming. Can some suggest a way to do it using CSS if possible. Attaching the example here.

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Are they two different components in one container?

Comment: Yes for now we have designed it as separate components in two containers, and aligned using margin, but screen to screen the alignment differs , so we would like to add text on top of the tick button using CSS if possible.

Comment: Bring your code to the fiddle http://fiddle.sencha.com

Answer (score 0):

CSS should solve your problem, this is a bit hard-coded and won't work as a generic solution but you can start from here:

First let's create a panel with progress bars and a button between them:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    height: 100,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'middle'
    },
    defaults: {
        margin: 2
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'progressbar',
        style: {
            borderRadius: '5px'
        },
        height: 10,
        width: 200,
        text: ' ',
        value: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        cls: 'btnWrapper',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            height: 30,
            cls: 'fa fa-check',
            style: {
                color: 'white'
            }
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'progressbar',
        style: {
            borderRadius: '5px'
        },
        height: 10,
        text: ' ',
        width: 200
    }]
});
```

And here is the CSS to take care of the rest:

```
<style>
    .btnWrapper:before {
        content: 'BASICS';
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        left: -10px;
        width: 100%;
        color: orange;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .btnWrapper .x-btn {
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21n5